# google analytics: what's the date range of front page numbers?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to GA. Below is my landing page for GA, but what is the date range for the circled portion? Is it all time since GA was installed on site? eg, have there been 1,332 visits on my site since the beginning of when Google Analytics was installed on the site?

[image: What is the date range of selected area?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for the date range you at the top of the page: Sept 12 - Oct 12. Basically, it is a rolling 30 day report.

Comment: That seems obvious now after you say that ;P, but I assumed that range was for only the graph. Thanks.

Comment: Click the little down arrow at the end of the date range to extend it out so you can see from your beginning of time or to pick different beginning and ending dates.